# how do i squash top 2 commits in git and automatically pick the oldest commit log

Tags: git

I understand that git rebase -i HEAD~2 would open the commits in an interactive mode. I want to skip all those steps and just squash those 2 top commits and pick the commit message from HEAD^. How can I accomplish that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

git reset --soft HEAD^ && git commit --amend --no-edit